# Using text search with MongoDB and Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I'm using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package for using MongoDB with Laravel:

And I'm trying to implement text search with MongoDB using this command:

```
db.place.find({$text:{$search:"hotel"}})
```

But I don't know how to translate this query to using it with above package and Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, how funny, I just found out the answer. Here is the code to get the result from text search:

```
\DB::collection('place')->raw()->find(array('$text'=>array('$search'=>'hotel')))->getNext();
```

Comment: I can only set my answer as correct in 2 day which mean by tomorrow I will

Comment: @tjntun where did you find this answer. Please provide any links if you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw) method.

```
Place::whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => 'hotel']])->get();
```

---

You can even make use of laravel [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) for defining common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application.

**Place Model**

```
public function scopeContains($query, $search)
{
    return $query->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => $search]]);
}
```

**Place Controller**

```
Place::contains('hotel')->get();
```